# How to bind to ICollection of the parent binding in DataGrid RowDetails? (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has row details to show a second row with the historical information of the row. I have this code in the XAML:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DgdTareas}"
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding DgdTareasSelectedIndex}"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="{Binding DgdTareasDetallesVisibility}">


    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="dgdTareasPiezasHistorico" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TareasPiezasHistorico}">
               <DataGrid.Columns>
                   <DataGridTextColumn Header="IDEstado" Binding="{Binding IDEstado, Mode=TwoWay}" />
               </DataGrid.Columns>
           </DataGrid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The main dataGrid, bind a colection of type Tareas. This object has a ICollection of type TareasHistorico.

So I would like that the itemsSource of the second dataGrid was Tareas.TareasHistorico, but I am not be able to bind this property.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps its just a spelling error? In the XAML snippet you're binding `TareasPiezasHistorico` but in the questions you're stating you want to bind `Tareas.TareasHistorico`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` used as the `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate` has the same object set as its `DataContext` as the `DataGrid.ItemsTemplate`, that is, an item from your data bound collection of type `Tareas`. Therefore, all you need to do is use the name of the `ICollection` property of the `Tareas` class in the `Binding Path` of the inner `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" 
   Name="dgdTareasPiezasHistorico" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"
   ItemsSource="{Binding NameOfICollectionPropertyInTareasClass}">
   ...
</DataGrid>
```

Of course, you must also ensure that the property has been declared as `public`.